# Can I install Google Chrome on a Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: chrome-for-android, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Is it possible to install Google Chrome on a Kindle Fire HD? I searched the Amazon store and didn't see it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. According to the guide [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1900651) on sideloading apps onto your Kindle Fire HD it should work fine. You will need to allow the installation of apps from unknown sources [which can be done in the Device menu](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=190447). Note that for certain apps, including Chrome, that need a Google account you'll need to download and install the [Google Framework](http://www.mediafire.com/?zaumfwhraxcifqf) and to reboot your device.

I'll provide a quick summary of the link that explains side loading:

1. The first thing you need to do is install a file manager app. I personally use File Expert, but you can use whatever works for you.
2. Next you need to get the app file. You can find it by searching on Google: (app name) apk. So in this case you would search 'chrome apk', there's plenty of links from that.
3. Once you have those, navigate to the Downloads folder with the file manager, and tap the .apk file. Click Install, and you're set!
4. You can find the app in apps>device, it will not be in Cloud.

Comment: There are Chrome APK files all over the place in file sharing sites. But couldn't they have viruses?  I'd like to download it from a recognized source (ideally Google). Any suggestions? Posted that here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43132/10645

Comment: Note that this doesn't allow you to login to your chrome account to get your bookmarks et. You will need to obtain (purchase) a third party Chrome sync app to do this final step.

Comment: If you are looking for a apk do NOT use use www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome/ version 67 it has a virus, on my Amazon Fire HD 10 it spawned some adware (ie3wisa4) if you see this website that mean you're are hacked. The reason why I think got hacked is because the apk is not secure or the Chrome browser itself. If you have been hacked reset your Fire to factory settings. YOU HAVE BEEN WARNED.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you may need to Flash a custom ROM, I think that Google Chrome requires ICS or better, but I am not sure, it may be specifically unavailable to your device or your devices stock firmware.
If you would like a custom ROM, then you'll need to start by rooting your phone.

Comment: Personally I don't think Google Chrome isn't as good as I expected though.

Comment: This answer will be only helpful if you can give more details like which ROM to keep and how.

Comment: This is a very generic answer that does not address the specific device.